# VirtualBox: Headless VM: Access web application from host machine.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, virtualbox, headless

I'm using VirtualBox (4.2.4) to run a headless Ubuntu 12.10 guest VM. I am able to ssh into it using putty with 127.0.0.1 on port 2222. The networking for the VM is configured as NAT for the first and only network adapter for the VM.

On the guest VM I'm running a development Rails web server on port 3000. Also when I run ifconfig on the headless VM it says that my IP address is 10.0.2.15 for eth0.

When I try to ping 10.0.2.15, I get nothing. When I try to access the web application from the host machine (Windows) at 127.0.0.1:3000, I get nothing. When I try to access the web app using 10.0.2.15, I get nothing.

What do I need to do to be able to access that web app from the browser on the Windows host machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure port forwarding or, even better, setup internal network.
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal

You may also need to configure windows firewall.